# newbie validate xml using xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, validation

I need validate an xml using xsd in .net,

my files

see next post

any help about it ? any sample code source ?

Answer (score 1):

See the following example [Validate an XML Document](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/Xml/XmlDocumentValidation.aspx). Looks about right to me.